# Bitfields and C++11 static_assert

Tags: c++11, bit-fields, static-assert

We all know that bit-fields are not very portable, and therefore should be avoided, to quote the C99 standard 6.7.2.1/10 - "Structure and union specifiers";

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

However; In dealing with hardware devices and such, one often have to deal with specific bit-layouts, which, without bit-fields, imply nasty and unreadable (at-least in my opinion) bit-fiddling code.

So what I'd like to do, is to use bit-fields, however I'd like to first validate that the bit-field layout the compiler generates, actually matches my expectations. So what I'm in the process of doing, is writing some static_asserts, which fails, in the case, that the layout doesn't match.

For instance; a simple size assertion;

```
struct bitField
{
    bool AC     : 1; // Accessed bit. Just set to 0. The CPU sets this to 1 when the segment is accessed.
    bool RW     : 1; // Readable bit/Writable bit. Is the code segment readable / data segment writeable.
    bool DC     : 1; // Direction bit/Conforming bit. 0=the segment grows up. 1=the segment grows down.
    bool EX     : 1; // Executable bit. If 1 code in this segment can be executed, ie. a code selector. If 0 it is a data selector.
    bool DT     : 1; // Descriptor type (Always 1?).
    uint8_t DPL   : 2; // Descriptor privilege level, 2 bits. - Contains the ring level, 0 = highest (kernel), 3 = lowest (user applications).
    bool P      : 1; // Present bit. - Is segment present? (1 = Yes). This must be 1 for all valid selectors.
};

static_assert(sizeof(bitField)==1,  "Incorrect size of bitfield");
```

This works as a charm, and ensures that the bit-field is always of correct size, however due to the implementation specific nature of bit-fields, I can't assume whether the layout inside of the bit-field is correct. So what I'm trying to do is, to static_assert the layout of the bit-field;

```
// Used to check that the bitfield, matches a specific required layout
union Bitfield_Layout_Checker
{   
    constexpr Bitfield_Layout_Checker(uint8_t raw) : raw(raw) {}

    constexpr bitField getBitField()
    {
        return format;
    }

    uint8_t raw;
    bitField format;
};

constexpr bool isBitfieldOkay()
{
    return Bitfield_Layout_Checker(0x01).getBitField().P == true;
}

static_assert(isBitfieldOkay(), "Bitfield layout not okay");
```

So this test, is supposed to check that the present bit, is in the correct place. - However when trying to compile the above code, using GCC v4.8.1 yields, this error message;

```
main.cpp:35:5: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
     static_assert(isBitfieldOkay(), "Bitfield layout not okay");
     ^
main.cpp:35:34:   in constexpr expansion of ‘isBitfieldOkay()’
main.cpp:32:58:   in constexpr expansion of ‘Bitfield_Layout_Checker(1).Bitfield_Layout_Checker::getBitField()’
main.cpp:35:5: error: accessing ‘Bitfield_Layout_Checker::format’ member instead of initialized ‘Bitfield_Layout_Checker::raw’ member in constant expression
```

Using Clang v3.1 yields, this error message;

```
a.cpp:35:19: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(isBitfieldOkay(), "Bitfield layout not okay");
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:23:20: note: read of member 'format' of union with active member 'raw' is not allowed in
  a constant expression
        return format;
               ^
a.cpp:23:20: note: in call to 'bitField(1.format)'
a.cpp:32:16: note: in call to ')'
    return Bitfield_Layout_Checker(0x01).getBitField().P == true;
           ^
a.cpp:35:19: note: in call to 'isBitfieldOkay()'
    static_assert(isBitfieldOkay(), "Bitfield layout not okay");
                  ^
```

Which indicates that I'm not allowed to read out the format field of the union, when it has been initialized through the raw field. So is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Unions aren't a magical panacea to get stuff you want. You have to play by the rules. Even a Baroness would agree with that.

Comment: Just make a class that hides the bit-twiddling, and access your named bits with a function.

Comment: The bit-fields are laid out correctly 99% of the time, and I'd honestly rather make a unit test, to catch issues, than I'd deal with bit-twiddling.

Comment: Well regardless, it is undefined behavior to read from a union member that has not been written to. (And in this case, this check is being done at compile-time hence the errors.) There is no way around this, it's the rules of a union (i.e., your claim that "it has been initialized through the raw field" is false).

Comment: @GManNickG, if the UB you refer to is a result of the type aliasing rules, I'm not sure it's undefined behavior since `char` and `unsigned char` are allowed to alias any other type, and `uint8_t` is (with high likelihood) an alias for one of those two types.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: Not type aliasing. It's just defined that a union only has one active member at a time, whichever one was last initialized. Many common uses of union (as a hack to bit-cast one type to another) are undefined behavior.

Comment: Due to the popularity of using bitfields in hardware device programming, all modern compilers that I know of use the same bitfield arrangement rules.  I seriously doubt the behavior will change as it would break a lot of existing code in a lot of important places.  Moreover, bit fields without a defined standard layout are rarely useful in everyday coding, which makes any compiler that doesn't have a standard layout for bitfields an unfavorable tool for device developers, and unlikely to gain traction in the industry.

Comment: I should clarify: all *little-endian* compilers.  Some big-endian compilers (namely IBM's PowerPC compiler) store bitfields MSB-to-LSB order.  For a project that we needed cross-platform to IBM's compiler, we declared our bitfields in a special markup and wrote a Python script that translated it into a C++ header at compile-time.  It generated unions with swapped bitfield order based on the MSB/LSB setting.